# Outlook conversation view - MOVE all items in conversation (no matter what folders) at once

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I am using conversation view and currently if I move something from my inbox to a subfolder it only moves the items in my inbox (even though it shows all other foldsers (including sent items) in the conversation.

I want to be able to move something from my inbox (or any other folder) and move the entire conversation to another folder (not just what is in my inbox).

So for example I have an email in my inbox and it has some items in my Sent folder as well.  Currently I have to move items from my inbox to a folder, then go to Sent folder and move the items from there to the folder as well.

I want it to move all items from inbox and sent folder to the folder at the same time so I do not have to move from 2 seperate folders.

Please let me know if this is possible and if so, how to do it.

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 3):

This issue has driven me nuts for almost a year but today I finally figured out a work around after 4 hours of trying (yes I'm a bit ocd).  There are two workarounds:

1. Create a rule to make a copy of every message that is sent in your inbox and then switch off saving of mail into "Sent Items".  Your sent messages will then be threaded in your inbox and you can just move the entire conversation to wherever you please.  However, this method is problematic if using google apps sync (as I am).  See below.
2. There is a simpler way to move all messages in a conversation including those in sent and that's what I've just found.  Expand the conversation completely.  Highlight all the messages by click the top one and shift clicking the bottom one.  Drag to desired folder.  Done.  I've trawled the net for months for a solution and haven't seen this one anywhere.  I'm just relieved I finally got a solution - the problem almost drove me out of Outlook to Googles awful web interface (gmail concepts are fantastic - the UI is just awful.  I wish they'd implement a stand alone email client so that all the problems of being in a web browser are resolved).

Note about Google Apps:

If using Google Apps, the gmail server creates a sent mail label for every message.  Sync then copies this to the sent items folder in Outlook.  It is smart enough to handle duplicates if you have Outlook set to copy all sent mail to Sent Items but not smart enough to handle the above rule, so you end up with duplicates of every sent message.

Comment: Method 2 doesn't seem to move messages in "Sent Items" on Outlook 2010. There's an option to keep the sent messages in the same folder but only if you don't replay from within the inbox. (!) Manually selecting the message in the conversation that's still in sent items and dragging does move it, though.

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with this too.  If you organize your inbox by 'conversation' - you can then click on the SUBJECT (which is the highest level of the top of the conversation) and drag it to your folder.  When you drag it over, all parts of the conversation - including sent items, will move.

Answer (score 0):

If you view the thread as a conversation (which will show the received and sent items) and then bulk select each item (hold cntl down, click on each individually or hold shift down, click on first and last) then move you will get all the items to the folder.

Be careful not to just select the 'Subject' as whilst you'll still see the sent items, they're still stored in the sent items folder. If you then move the folder out of your cached mailbox to another location you won't see the sent items.

You can easily check whether you have succeeded (and this is dependent on your viewing preference) - if you can still see the lighter grey '*sent items*' in place of the day/time stamp on each item, it is still in sent items. If you now see the day/time stamp, you have succeeded